# In Sydney does string still zero based in mobile?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

when I read the doc: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop it's say that in mobile string is 0-Based, but I heard that it's not the case anymore, so is the doc inaccurate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "..so is the doc inaccurate ?"

Yes, the document you are reading is not updated with the latest information.

See [Zero-based strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)):

> Compilers (desktop and mobile) have as predefined {$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF} indicating the use 1-based string indexes.
>
> ***Note:** Previous to Delphi 10.4 the mobile compilers used by default 0-based indexing for strings.*

You can still use zero-based strings by setting `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS ON}`

Also from docs:

> In general terms, string indexing is now uniform across platforms and uses 1-based index model.
>
> Notice however that:
>
> - Delphi string type helpers (TStringHelper) remain 0-based.
> - All Delphi global flat functions are 1-based.

Answer (score 1):

The doc is inaccurate at several places: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31133